# ¿Cómo mostrar valor de una columna en un input cuando he seleccionado un elemento mediante un select?

Tags: php, html5

Estoy tratando de mostrar el valor de un ítem seleccionado en un `<select>` en un `<input type=text>` o en un `<label>, es decir, primeramente cargo el`  con la información que obtengo en una consulta realizada a la tabla de la base de datos:

```
<?php
   include("db.php");
   $con = conectar();
   $sql1 = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT COD_SERVICIO, DESCRIPCION_SERVICIO, COSTO_SERVICIO FROM servicios");

   $fechaAct = date("Y-m-d");
   $estado = "P";
?>
```

```
<select id="servicios" name="servicios">
  <?php
    while ($servicios = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $servicios['COD_SERVICIO'] ?>"><?php echo$servicios['DESCRIPCION_SERVICIO'] ?></option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

y a parte como ya mencione al inicio quiero mostrar el  `COSTO_SERVICIO` del ítem que se ha seleccionado; lo que voy a mostrar a continuación se que tiene errores y quiero aprender a darle solución

```
<label for="costo"><strong>Costo</strong>
                     <input type="text" name="costoServicio" value="<?php echo $sql1['COSTO_SERVICIO']?>"></td>
```

también he intentado cambiar de lugar el cierre de corchete `}` de la sentencia `while` del código php embebido en el html al después del input que contendrá dicho costo y se da un error ya que no se visualizan los elementos que tengo después, a continuación esta una captura de lo que obtengo visualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo arreglar esta parte?**

Answer (score 0):

Tendrías que usar Javascript y modificar un poco el HTML.
Javascript para responder a la selección de servicios y modificar el valor del campo input añadiéndole un atributo **data-costo**.

```
<select id="servicios" name="servicios" onchange="ponCosto()">
  <?php
    while ($servicios = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1)) {
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $servicios['COD_SERVICIO'] ?>" data-costoserv ="<?php echo $servicios['COSTO_SERVICIO'] ?>"><?php echo$servicios['DESCRIPCION_SERVICIO'] ?>  </option>
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Ahora tienes activo el evento **onchange** y cada opción tiene un atributo **data-costo** con el costo del servicio.
En la función **ponCosto()** que se invoca cuando seleccionas una opción

```
function valor(){
    var ind = event.target.selectedIndex;  
    var valor = event.target.item(ind).dataset.costoserv;
    document.getElementById('costo').value = valor;
}
```

Lo primero que hace es anotar en **ind** el índice de la opción seleccionada. Lee el atributo data-costo del elemento option seleccinado. Por último anota el valor en el control **input**
Pon el script antes que el formulario para que onchange no te falle, y pon el valor inicial a input que se corresponda con el valor seleccionado. Puedes poner un primer campo option con valor "Seleccionar servicio " y data-costoser='', por ejemplo.